# i want to make a function or macro that will return the current code location in the format of namespace.class.function()

Tags: c#

i basically want to call this function code to get some metrics and so it needs to know what is the location of the execution code right now.
so i can use this location to log the code executing position.
is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.

```
public void CallerTest()
{
    CallerInformation();
}

public void CallerInformation()
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame caller = stackTrace.GetFrame(1); // The caller
    int callLineNumber = caller.GetFileLineNumber();
    System.Reflection.MethodBase callerMethod = caller.GetMethod();
    string callerName = callerMethod.ReflectedType.FullName + "." + callerMethod.Name;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(string.Format("Caller - Line:{0} Method:{1}", callLineNumber, callerName));
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to get the StackTrace; but note that it'll be pretty slow.  Make sure you don't over use this!

Comment: Indeed. You should heed Akmad's warning about the performance of using reflection. Doing this excessively will slow things down.

Comment: well this will be only used to trace/debug so it will be only used in limited places :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - yes, I **guess** it's possible, but I'm not sure. 
You'll need to read up on Reflection - you can dynamically construct and compile assemblies on the fly, so I would imagine you'll be able to do what you want - or something near enough.

Sorry - the way you've worded your question makes it a little hard to understand what you want to do.  Ignoring the technical specifics of what you want to do (inject a function) - what is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: emm i tried to clear it up a little, its not inject, its basically call